# Do Hot Partitions in Cosmos increase RU consumption?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a multi-tenant system in Cosmos that has the tenant id as the partition key for the container. Due to architectural issues I have always known that there is a number of hot partitions and some other that are practically idle. So far this was only a problem of unevenly distributed throughput between tenants and requests getting throttled for the hot partitions, but now I'm seeing a big increase in RU consumption in some queries that didn't use to exceed 100 RUs.

This query in my dev environment costs around 30 RUs, but it's getting to 500 RUs in production.

```
SELECT
    MAX(c._ts) AS CosmosMaxTimestamp
FROM
    c
WHERE
    c.type ='myType'
    AND
    c.tenantId = '<random-guid>'
```

Looking at possible answers to the increase in consumption I understand that the size of the data source is part of the RU equation. My production db is about 5gb heavier than dev, but is it enough to explain such a big jump in RU consumption or does the hot partitions problem in production contribute to it?

Update:
I compared the query metrics between environments and there isn't any noticeable differences other than Request Charge.

---

Comment: How many records would be there ?

Comment: Does this article help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/distribute-throughput-across-partitions - it documents some PowerShell commands you can run to troubleshoot hot-partitions. As for the RU cost - _it depends_ - we need more details about your database and application.

Comment: I think redistro for data skew would get you a solution.

Comment: Query costs are based on the query, and your partitioning scheme. If you're running a cross-partition query, then costs go up as the number of (physical) partitions queried increases. Is this a single-partition query? Cross-partition?

Comment: @DavidMakogon this is a single partition query, tenantId is the partition key for the container.

Comment: Can you capture the Query Metrics or Diagnostics from executing the operation to compare? Maybe one has different Indexing Policy

Comment: @Dai what kind of details? happy to update the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of monitoring and research, I've come to the conclusion that the increase in RU consumption is more a symptom of Hot Partitions rather than a direct result.

When looking at the Insights of the db resource on Azure I found my partitions to be unevenly distributed in terms of storage. My hot partitions were at around 1gb whereas cool partitions could be as small as 100mb. When running the query against one of the big partitions the RUs go up to 1000 as opposed to 15 RUs for small partitions. This made me think that something could be wrong with indexes so I went through index docs, where I found the following on [scalar aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#index-utilization-for-scalar-aggregate-functions) :

> Queries with the following aggregate functions must rely exclusively on the index, so evaluating some system functions requires a full scan.

And under the definition for [Full Scans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#full-index-scan):

> Full scans don't use the index and have an RU charge that increases linearly
> with the total data size."

With this I can conclude that one of the causes of Hot Partitions is unevenly distributed data between partitions, which can result in some type of queries consuming more or less RUs for different partitions, but **having Hot Partitions should not increase RU consumption.** Instead (obviously), having high RUs is the cause of Hot Partitions.

In my case, applying an aggregate function on partitions that grow in size over time is the cause of the increase in RUs and is aggravating the hot partitions issue.